# Symfony2 - Requirements for post parameters

Tags: php, rest, symfony, post, routes

I am relativeley new to Symfony and building a Rest API with the FriendsOfSymfony RestBundle.

My problem is that I want to use the requirements, which I used for my GET routes, for my POST routes. Is there any way to do so?

So practically something like this:

```
@Post("/article/{articleId}", requirements={"articleId"="\d+"})
```

Apparantly the ParamFetcher is also only for GET parameters although I couldn't find any specific information about this.

I'd be greatful for any help on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

The ParamFetcher works just fine with POST parameters as well. You can use the annotation:

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\RequestParam;

```
/**
 * @RequestParam(
 *   name="",
 *   key=null,
 *   requirements="",
 *   default=null,
 *   description="",
 *   strict=true,
 *   array=false,
 *   nullable=false
 * )
 */
```

Just remember to enable the related listeners otherwise it won't work:

```
fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    body_listener: true
```

Reference and documentation here: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/3-listener-support.md